# How to pass argv[0] with Process.Start in C#

Tags: c#, clang, android-source, argv

I'm writing a wrapper program in C# with Mono under Ubuntu. The key of a successful wrapper is to be as transparent as possible. One of the requirement is to pass argv through exactly.

When use Process.Start to start the wrapped program, how can we pass argv[0] to the wrapped program? It seems that we can't pass argv[0] at all, it is just 
 set to the wrapped program's executable full path.

Some program's behavior may depends on argv[0]. This is true for AOSP's prebuilt clang tool set. For example, under

```
prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-4691093/bin$
```

there is lld, this program obvious check argv[0] to decide which symbol link you invoke (ld.lld/ld-link/ld64.lld). If you don't invoke lld through predefined symbol links, lld will report error.

With C/C++, it is easy to set argv[0] to the symbol link's name to successfully invoke lld. But can we do this in C#?

Comment: You can provide arguments (as a string) as the second parameter of `Process.Start`, or use `ProcessStartInfo` instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ KookieMonster  to write a wrapper, the need here is to provide an argv[0] string to the wrapped program that is different than the  full path of the wrapped program. With API you mentioned, the wrapped program always get an argv[0] that is its own full path.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the problem. It may be doable in .NET, but I'm not sure. If you can do it in C/C++ however, then can't you just invoke the native code from C#? (aka P/Invoke, `DLLImport`, etc)?

Comment: @ KookieMonster Yes, indeed the better way is write a C/C++ wrapper that delegate real job of pre-processing and post-processing to C# programs which is much easier to write. But the general question still exist.